# Two different deployments on nginx

Tags: nginx

I have two applications that I need to serve using the same nginx server.

The first one should run under help.example.com. The other one, has a domain for each customer, like foo.example.com and bar.example.com

I understand that nginx gives preferences to longer server names, but I can't seem to find an example that will help me.

I tried to use two nginx conf files but I failed. Here are the "specs":

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.example.com.br example.com.br;
    root /opt/apps/gsa-web/src/;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;

}
```

help.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.help.example.com.br help.example.com.br;
    root /path-to-my-docs/docs_site/;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location / {
    }
}
```

Comment: "I understand that nginx gives preferences to longer server names"  Your understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, in the same configuration file you will have:

`server {
    listen 80;`

```
server_name www.help.example.com.br help.example.com.br;
root /path-to-my-docs/docs_site/;
client_max_body_size 4G;

location / {
```

}

AND

`server {
    listen 80;`

```
server_name *.example.com.br; # Notice the wildcard. 
root /opt/apps/gsa-web/src/;
client_max_body_size 4G;

location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 1800;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
```

}

The wildcard will allow all subdomains that aren't help to redirect to the configuration. Further reading: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names

Comment: wow that simple? let me try it ou and I'll let you know.

Comment: @George How did it go?

Comment: About to test this now :D